# Seamlessly solve square linear system that could be 1-dimensional in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am solving a linear system of equations `Ax=b`.
It is known that `A` is square and of full rank, but it is the result of a few matrix multiplications, say `A = numpy.dot(C,numpy.dot(D,E))` in which the result can be `1x1` depending on the inputs `C,D,E`. In that case `A` is a `float`.

`b` is ensured to be a vector, even when it is a `1x1` one.

I am currently doing

```
A = numpy.dot(C,numpy.dot(D,E))
try:
    x = numpy.linalg.solve(A,b)
except:
    x = b[0] / A
```

I searched numpy's documentation and didn't find other alternatives for `solve` and `dot` that would accept scalars for the first or output arrays for the second. Actually `numpy.linalg.solve` requires dimension at least 2. If we were going to produce an `A = numpy.array([5])` it would complain too.

Is there some alternative that I missed?

Comment: Why is `A` a float in the 1x1 case? It sounds like that's the underlying problem that needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

> in which the result can be 1x1 depending on the inputs C,D,E. In that case A is a float.

This is not true, it is a 1x1 matrix, as expected

```
x=np.array([[1,2]])
z=x.dot(x.T)  # 1x2 matrix times 2x1
print(z.shape) # (1, 1)
```

which works just fine with linalg.solve

```
linalg.solve(z, z) # returns [[1]], as expected
```

Comment: You are right about your example. I probably don't know something about how `array` and `dot` work. Why is it that you initialize `x=np.array([[1,2]])` instead of `x=np.array([1,2])` ?

Comment: I think I understood now combining your idea with user2357112's answer. If I do `numpy.atleast_2d(numpy.array([1,2]))` it produces `[[1,2]]`. An initialization like `numpy.array([1,2])` actually produces a `(2,)` array.

Comment: I initialize x in such a way because this is the only proper way to initialize the matrix. If you initialize it with [1,2] then it is a vector, not a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

While you could expand the dimensions of `A`:

```
A = numpy.atleast_2d(A)
```

it sounds like `A` never should have been a float in the first place, and you should instead fix whatever is causing it to be one.